# Combine Spring RESTFul microservice with MVC view

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc, client-server, spring-boot

I would like to set up something like client-server communication over restful webservice (service only on "server" side) and render data retrieved from client in web application running with restful microservice.

[image: example flow]

My question is whether I need to have separate applications on server side (one for restful service, second for web application) in order to have this functionality or there is some other way to combine web service with MVC web application.

If my approach is wrong please give me some suggestions of how to achieve such thing.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by storing command result in the server context. WebApp with separate request (could by asynchronous) retrieve the result from the context and render in view.